# How to see console.log in while code execution google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function setCredentials(request) {
  var key = request.key;

  // Optional
  // Check if the provided key is valid through a call to your service.
  // You would have to have a `checkForValidKey` function defined for
  // this to work.
  var fetchOptions = {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + key
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };

var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com/api/check', fetchOptions)

  console.log("res ", res)

  if (res.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    return cc.newSetCredentialsResponse()
      .setIsValid(true)
      .build();
  }else{
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    userProperties.setProperty('dscc.key', key);
    return cc.newSetCredentialsResponse()
      .setIsValid(false)
      .build();
  }
```

The above code has console.log response from the url fetch, while code execution where i can see these console log?

I did try to see in the **execution log** of the script, but i couldn't found it.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `I did try to see in the execution log of the script, but i couldn't found it.`, in your script, how about modifying `console.log("res ", res)` to `console.log("res ", res.getContentText())` or `console.log(res.getContentText())`? I think that `fetch` returns an object of UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse. In order to retrieve the text data of the response, `getContentText()` is required to be used. But, if binary data is returned, please retrieve a blob with `res.getBlob()`. By this, this data can be saved as a file.

Comment: I mean when i try to execute the app script using [link](https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/1/datasources/create?connectorId=AKfycbwSeT8xSi6ac_tOlwsDS_gbDuyJwcMKi9x5W4u_vCNT) , i am not able to see the realtime execution error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself.

I have to do is **Logger.log()** inside function.

And after execution,[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN7ZO.png) I can check here you can see in the image.